# Android Couchbase Lite Replication

Tags: android, couchdb, couchbase-lite, couchbase-sync-gateway

I am having issues getting the replication function to work for my local Couchbase database and my Android app:

```
private void startSync() {
    URL syncUrl;
    try {
        syncUrl = new URL("http://10.0.2.2:4984/sync_gateway"); // I am testing with the Android emulator

        manager = new Manager(new AndroidContext(this), Manager.DEFAULT_OPTIONS);
        database = manager.getDatabase("db");

        Replication pullReplication = database
                .createPullReplication(syncUrl);
        pullReplication.setContinuous(true);
        pullReplication.addChangeListener(this);
        pullReplication.start();

    }
    catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (CouchbaseLiteException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    Query query = database.createAllDocumentsQuery();
    query.setAllDocsMode(Query.AllDocsMode.ALL_DOCS);
    QueryEnumerator result;
    try {
        result = query.run();

        for (Iterator<QueryRow> it = result; it.hasNext(); ) {
            QueryRow row = it.next();
            Log.i("CouchActivity", "Getting document i: " + row.getDocumentId());
        }
    }
    catch (CouchbaseLiteException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Once I have created a pull replication, I proceed to query all the documents for the local database, but no documents are returned.

My config file for the sync gateway is as follows:

```
{
  "interface": ":4984",
  "adminInterface": ":4985",
  "log": ["REST"],
  "databases": {
    "sync_gateway": {
    "server": "http://localhost:8091",
    "bucket": "stations",
    "sync": `function(doc) {channel(doc.channels);}`,
    "users": { "GUEST": { "disabled": false, "admin_channels": ["*"] } }
    }
  }
}
```

When I type in localhost:4984/sync_gateway, I do get a response of "

```
{"committed_update_seq":1,"compact_running":false,"db_name":"sync_gateway","disk_format_version":0,"instance_start_time":1471324911376777,"purge_seq":0,"state":"Online","update_seq":1}"
```

Not sure if the issue is with the **Android** side, as I do see the sync gateway **output "POST /sync_gateway/_changes"** when I run my Android code. Can anyone explain why replication is not working?

Update - I was able to confirm that my setup was done correctly. The issue that I was having had to do with the way I created my documents. The ones that I created through the admin console did not have the metadata that is required in order to be recognized as a valid document. I ended up populating the server side database by populating the database through my app via push replication. Creating a document via the POST request should also work.

Comment: What do you expect to see in the result of the all docs query on Couchbase Lite? The response from sync gateway indicates that there are no changes to replicate (update_seq=1). You can add a new document on Sync Gateway through the REST API (see the spec for a curl request example http://developer.couchbase.com/mobile/swagger/sync-gateway-public/#!/document/post_db) and then check whether it's returned by the all docs query on Couchbase Lite.

Comment: The documents were all added through the admin console. Shouldn't the initial pull still sync the three documents that are in the database. I'll give that request a try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are adding documents through the **Admin Console**, you are missing the Sync Gateway in between. The tracking of changes for a particular Document(it's sequence number) is maintained at the Sync Gateway. So when an Agent is trying to pull a Document it finds no changes in reference to its local DB and hence you receive nothing.
To actually pull a document you have to first Push it from your agent **through the Sync Gateway**. Admin Console directly adds documents to the SQL tables at server which has no co-relation to Sync gateway.